# How to round up currency with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, currency

How can I round up different type of currencies with using jquery? What I'm trying to do is;

```
10.30 → 10 //Below .5 will round down
10.60 → 11 //After .5 will round up
849.95 → 850
1,022.20 → 1022
```

Comment: Please search before asking new questions. Rounding is a simple concept that has many very similar questions already.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`Math.round()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

> The [**`Math.round()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) function returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

**Please Note:** The number with comma is a string and you have to remove the comma. Then you can convert that back to number with `Number()`, finally implement [**`Math.round()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
console.log(Math.round(10.30));// → 10 //Below .5 will round down
console.log(Math.round(10.60))// → 11 //After .5 will round up
console.log(Math.round(849.95));// → 850
console.log(Math.round(Number('1,022.20'.replace(/,/g, ''))));// → 1022
```

Comment: Me again, tried your version to fix it but I'm having a problem if the currency from Europe. For example €22,34. But it works perfectly fine with rest of it. https://jsfiddle.net/ug2veqbh/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a jquery plugin: https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric
Then it's as simple as:

```
new AutoNumeric('.myInput', { 
  roundingMethod: AutoNumeric.options.roundingMethod.halfUpSymmetric 
});
```